# How to transition from getString rapidjson to std::string

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I want to assign a string value from [rappidjson](http://miloyip.github.io/rapidjson/) to my variable class.

```
void MyClass::setName(Ch* jsonString) 
{
    _name = (std::string)jsonString; 
}
```

Comment: If you're getting an error, can you add that to your question?

Comment: Is this not working? What is the error (don't comment, update your post with extra information).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

```
void MyClass::setName(Ch* jsonString)
{
   _name = jsonString;
}
```